# Create QlikView task through command line

Tags: powershell, command-line, qlikview

I want to be able to create a task for qvw files with a command (cmd, powershell, etc), just as you would through the QlikView Management Console. We would like to be able to automate some of the task creation remotely which would require this functionality.

I know that there are arguments that can be passed through the qv.exe to reload the document, but I want to actually create a task through a command line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think that this is possible out of the box. You can control QV server through `QlikView Management Services API`. But for this reason you need to build a `.net` command line app that will do whatever you want.

If you are interested follow [this link](http://www.qlikblog.at/1864/qliktip-qlikview-mangement-services-api_qmsapi/) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I have successfully accessed the QlikView service using this API with a .net program. Unfortunately I have not been able to find a method that can be used to create a task. I've searched through the documentation and searched/posted on the QlikView Community site.

Comment: I need to dig in my code files. I'm pretty sure that I've done this somewhere. Will post here when I find it.

Comment: This is exactly copy-paste from my project. There is some extra code that probably you don't need https://gist.github.com/countnazgul/0069a00b8dc275445692e9284de337bc

Comment: Appreciate the code, I am making progress. What did you use as a documentation reference for the QMSAPI classes/methods? I have been looking the through the official documentation that I got from here https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-2683 , but is seems to be lacking in a number of areas. Also any google result that redirects to a help.qlik URL regarding the QMSAPI is not functioning for me.

Comment: I haven't use/found much of documentation as well. Mostly used the service reference to see the methods and classes from within VS. Also at some point used the QMS API tool (https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-3059) to get the responses. But in general it was try and error approach.

Comment: Would you happened to have worked with selecting fields and values in the reduce section of the tasks? I have been able to create TaskReduceStatic and TaskReduceDynamic objects to fit into the reduce property, but I am lost as to how to select fields and values after one would have pressed "open document" in the management console GUI.

Comment: Haven't done this but sound interesting. Will play with it and will let you know.

Comment: I managed to add a selected field and value by going into the DocumentTask.TaskReduce.TaskReduceStatic object. I was required to create a TaskReduction object as well as a TaskReductionField object to place inside of it. After settings the values of the properties inside these objects accordingly and putting the TaskReduction instance into an Array and adding the array to Static.Reductions it worked. You can see my solution to my own problem here https://community.qlik.com/thread/224566

Comment: Nice :) Its a powerful api but you need to write too much code sometimes for not so complicated (as i think) tasks

Comment: I'm now attempting to add a "Distribute to QlikView Server " with a number of users but I'm having issues, was wondering if you have worked with the API managing the distribute category? I made a question about my specific issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338200/qlikview-management-api-erroring-when-including-distribute